# Sequelize find based on conditions

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have x account in which 50 members are listed including the creator of the account.
I want to display list of members of that account in such a way that logged-in user should appear at the top and then apply another sorting.
Note: Api will contain skipCount(offset) and LimitCount(limit)  .The above logic will be applied only if skipCount is 0 **(logged-in user should appear at the top)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have a logged-in user id as `loggedUserId` then you can do such sorting like this:

```js
const order = []
if (skipCount === 0) {
  order.push([Sequelize.literal('($userId = accounts.id)'), 'DESC'])
}
order.push(<other sorting>)

const accounts = await Accounts.findAll({
  bind: {
    userId: loggedUserId
  },
  order,
  limit: LimitCount,
  offset: skipCount
})
```